# Firebase only sends expired verification link

Tags: reactjs, firebase, frontend, email-verification

I'm using firebase for my react app . I want to send a email verification link to my user's email and the email sends successfully **but the problem is exactly when the verification email link sends to my email and I click on it this is what I get** :
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4apn2.png) (click to see it)

this is what I did :

```
  const sendVerificationLink = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      await sendEmailVerification(currentUser);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("verification link snet success");
      console.log(err);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    sendVerificationLink();
  }, []);
```

**One interesting thing is that if use a temporary email e.g. from https://temp-mail.org it will working correctly but if I use my personal email it doesn't work and give me that error** please help me guys it's really important.
thanks.

Comment: please check this question - it does not have an accepted answer but there are a lot of suggestions for solving this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145370/firebase-only-sends-already-expired-email-verification-links