# Reset password with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can send reset email as follow :

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            String emailAddress = email.getText().toString();

            auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

But after I open the received email, I just found this message with out any action  :

> Try resetting your password again
>   Your request to reset your password has expired or the link has already been used

How I can reset Password Completely?

Comment: The code seems fine. The reset link is only valid for a limited amount of time to prevent abuse. If you think you've clicked the link in a reasonable amount of time but are still having this problem, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yup, i think 2 mint is not that much time, what about have my own website with that, and just use firebase for sending message only?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i also tried solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38160622/7913931)

Comment: @ArduinoAndroid have you found what is the wrong because am facing similar issue

Answer (score 0):

try adding addOnSuccessListener in which you can get actual exception or result that why email receive expired reset link..

```
auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
      public void onSuccess(Void result) {
        // send email succeeded
      }
   }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
      public onFailure(Exception e)
        // something bad happened
      }
   });
```

Comment: you think it can help me with that purpose ! ?