# sendPasswordResetEmail return now "your password has expired or the link has already been used"

Tags: android, firebase, error-handling

I was contacted by one of my app users and he reports me that he can't recover his password. I tried to reproduce his problem and found that the firebase link returns now next error message when trying to access it to recover the user password:

"Try resetting your password again
Your request to reset your password has expired or the link has already been used"

The time between sending a request and clicking the link is around a minute.

I want to specify that one year ago when I implemented this feature all work perfectly.

My code for reset password request is:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(txtEmail.getText().toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    showSuccessPopup();
                } else {
                    showFailPopup();
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            });
```

Something was modified last year to this option on firebase?

Comment: Check this, many answers maybe one can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160622/firebase-reset-password-link-not-working

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604447/14759470