# Firebase auth emails are expired when clicked

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am implementing email login in my app and it worked when I setup the project i.e. when I implemented it. I might have deleted some API key in my google console or something but now every time I click on the link inside the emails (verification or reset) I get the message:

**Try verifying your email again**

*Your request to verify your email has expired or the link has already been used*

I know this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160622/firebase-reset-password-link-not-working), however I can't seem to find an answer.

The link of the email I receive has an API key attached. The attached API key does not appear anywhere in my google cloud console. It appears in my firebase console under:

```
Web API key: the_web_api_key
```

Therefore the link I receive in the emails looks like this:

`https://<appName>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=
<oobCode>&apiKey=<the_web_api_key>`

However this `the_web_api_key` does not match the `apiKey` in my config initialisation object. There you can find the **legacy server key**:

```
let config = {
  apiKey: legacy_server_key,
  authDomain: "<appname>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<appname>.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "<appname>",
  storageBucket: "<appname>",
  messagingSenderId: "<senderId>"
}
```

The legacy server key appears as a server key in my google cloud console.

Maybe that could be the problem? Should I be using the Web Api Key in the initialisation object? I remember this working in the past how it currently is, so I am just confused.

Comment: Try creating a new API Key in your Google Cloud Console, not sure if it would make a difference but use this as the name "Browser key (auto created by Google Service)"   After creating it, the Firebase console should update it as well.

Comment: @Gerardo tried it. Still the issue. I contacted firebase support to see what is going on.

Comment: @Gerardo I changed the API key at the end of the link of the email to the `legacy_server_key` and it worked! How do I make this the default?

Comment: @Gerardo Now its working again. With the web api key as default.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround to reset the password that worked for me was to swap out the old API key with your new API key in the password reset email link.

Get the link from the password reset email it sends you when you reset your password:

https://(PROJECT-ID).firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=DLAe_N4ZmPUA0r7TYa0Il9NCjsc1edkt7F3PouX060UAAAFyPoDCUg&apiKey=(OLD-API-KEY)&lang=en

and update it with the new key:

https://(PROJECT-ID).firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=DLAe_N4ZmPUA0r7TYa0Il9NCjsc1edkt7F3PouX060UAAAFyPoDCUg&apiKey=(NEW-API-KEY)&lang=en

You can find your API key in Google's console: 
https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?folder=&organizationId=&project=(PROJECT-ID)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cliff thank you very much for the answer,
I wanted to add to this, There is no way to update the Firebase WEB API key set. I had to delete the automatically selected API key and then it's auto-shuffled to the other API key I wanted. Later I restored it on the GCP platform.

But it's really annoying and hopefully, they solve it. I opened a ticket on their end also. Hope this helps.

Summary:

1. Delete the Other Key from the GCP
2. Firebase will automatically set the other Key to be the Web API Key (Can't manually change from the website).
3. Restore the old key :) if you need it.

Hope it helps.