# Firebase auth password reset sends expired link

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, credentials

I'm creating a flutter app and use Firebase Auth, everything works just fine including Facebook and Google sign ins, however, once password reset link is sent via email, it shows up as already expired.

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274531/4743190) which states "you need to include the app itself which is where the emails originate: .firebaseapp.com", I don't understand what type of credential needs to be added. Could someone look at the images below and advice what is missing? Or is this not the problem in my case? What else should I check?

Credentials:
[image]

Firebase console:
[image]

Webpage:
[image]

Answer (score 14):

In case anyone runs into an issue like this, here's what solved my issue (thank you, Firebase support!!!).

- Go to Cloud Console, under APIs & Services > Credentials
- Select API key that has "Restrictions" as "HTTP referers" (See question picture "Credentials").
- Under "Application restrictions", add https://Project_ID.firebaseapp.com (hence you need to copy your Project ID from the firebase console (See question picture "Firebase console")

In my case I had AWS cognito credentials there and since I've moved to Firebase it was not updated.

Comment: Omg...you're my hero. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me I simply had to add my app’s Firebase URl in the website restriction settings in the Google Cloud Platform.

[image: Image of the website restriction page]